# sudo: setreuid(ROOT_UID, user_uid): Operation not permitted

Tags: debian, sudo

I get this in my debian wheezy. I do not know what to do. I get it with every sudo command. Su password fails every time. I have seen people suggesting running `service ncsd stop` and then start it but my command line doesnt recognise command "service". Any ideas?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you touch to permissions of `/usr/bin/sudo`? Or to mount options... Read about [setuid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid)

Comment: Can you show us what you did, and what happened? It is not clear what you are doing, or what the problem is.

Comment: Your question is the only occurrence of `server ncsd stop` that Google finds, so you should pay more attention to what you read and always copy-paste commands. Does `service nscd restart` help? Have you read http://askubuntu.com/questions/106642/how-to-fix-sudo-setreuidroot-uid-user-uid-operation-not-permitted-error ?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch The error message isn't consistent with bad permissions on the `sudo` binary nor with a filesystem mounted with `nosuid`.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. It was a typo (stupid human brain - constantly making mistakes). Corrected the questiom

Comment: @Gilles Yes I have

Comment: @Christopher typo. That wasnt my prob